# How to load many to many realtionship into objects

Tags: vb.net, many-to-many

This is done in vb.net. Application was started in vs 2005 sa no Entity Framework for me.

I have a Team object and Training object. 
Teams have mandatory Trainings.
Trainings are mandatory for multiple Teams.
Classic many to many relationship (DB wise)

I have a problem loading the data from DB to my objects.
How do I load Teams or Trainings (lists) seperately? 
Is it even possible to do?
Or do I always have to load them from the DB together.

It seems that in Order to load Teams I need to have Trainings preloaded, but to load Trainings I nedd the Teams first.

Team object has a list of Trainings field

Trainings object has a list of Team field

Comment: How are those two object linked? The Team object has a property as a List<Trainings>?

Comment: Have to give us some code, there's no technical reason why you can't load them separately. Can't be sure what issue you think there is.

Comment: You can load Training/Team and after that load the link between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Sqlcommands/SqlDataReaders, you can first read from DB the information about a Team object (except training objects), initialize the list of training objects as new List(), and the with a second command, read the list of training based on the id of the Team object (assuming you have somewhere the link based on id).

You can also read initially the entire list of Teams and then for each of them, in a second step initialize and read the  list of Training for each of them. You can reverse these step in order to get the list of Training that have details as a list of Team.

Comment: would that not lead to mutliple queries against the database to read all the details?

Comment: Indeed this will generate lot of reads in DB. If this is expensive, you could try read all the data at once (the join between Teams and Trainings), initialize both lists as blanks, and then for each joined record  check if current Training exist in Trainings and if not create object and add it to the list (if exists keep the found object in a var for late use), then do the same for Team, and then add Team object to Training object list of Teams and then Training to the Team.